# Change font size of dynamic table header using react

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, node.js, reactjs

[image: this is the output]

Im' working on a project where we are creating a UI and i'm trying to change the font size of my table's cells using react but whatever i do it doesn't seem to work... i tried using "fontSize: 30," and also fontSize: "30pt", but nothing seems to work

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import DynamicTable from '@atlaskit/dynamic-table';

export const caption = 'List of Addon Version';

export const createHead = (withWidth) => {
    return {
      cells: [
        {
            
          key: 'pluginName',
          content: 'Plugin Name',
          shouldTruncate: true,
          isSortable: true,
          fontSize: 30,
          width: withWidth ? 25 : undefined,
             
        },
        
        {
      key: 'pluginVersion',
          content: 'Plugin Version',
          shouldTruncate: true,
          isSortable: true,
          width: withWidth ? 25 : undefined,
      fontSize: 30,
        },
        {
          key: 'jiraVersion',
          content: 'Jira Version Group',
          shouldTruncate: true,
      width: withWidth ? 25 : undefined,
      isSortable: true,
      fontSize: 30,
        },
        {
     key: 'pluginKey',
     content: 'Plugin Key',
     shouldTruncate: true,
     width: withWidth ? 25 : undefined,
     fontSize: 30,
        },
      ],
  };
};
```

i would appreciate any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well cells don't take a fontSize prop. Thats why its not working for you.
But you can use `styled-components` to adjust the styling of the table. Check out the example below.

```
import React from 'react';

import styled from 'styled-components';

import DynamicTable from '@atlaskit/dynamic-table';

import { caption, head, rows } from './design-system/dynamic-table/examples/content/sample-data';

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  min-width: 600px;
  td{font-size:30px}
`;

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default class extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <DynamicTable
          caption={caption}
          head={head}
          rows={rows}
          rowsPerPage={5}
          defaultPage={1}
          isFixedSize
          defaultSortKey="term"
          defaultSortOrder="ASC"
          onSort={() => console.log('onSort')}
          onSetPage={() => console.log('onSetPage')}
        />
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

The styled div `Wrapper` has taken a width attribute, but we can also nest styling attributes for elements inside of `Wrapper`. I've added `font-size` styling for the `td` tags.

Check out the code on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pw122?module=/example.tsx&file=/example.tsx:0-828), add the `td{font-size:30px}` where I added it to see its effects. You can style whatever you want within the `Wrapper`, just make sure to add the correct classes / tags / id's.

And check out the props that cells can actually take:

[image]

Source of image: [@atlaskit/dynamic-table docs](https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/packages/design-system/dynamic-table)